# codeigniter validation_errors() being populated prematurely

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

i have a view in which i am using a form with radio buttons to display all employees in a company. (im using a simple java script to allow the form to be submitted without using a submit button and to pass an employees id into the controller onclick of a radio button)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
function submit ()
{
        document.select_employee.submit() ;
}

--></script>

<title>Employee Master</title>

<a href="<?php echo (base_url('index.php/employee_master/add_employee'))?>">Add New     Employee </a>
<a href="javascript:submit()">Edit Employee</a>
<a href="">Delete Employee </a>
<br />
<?php $id_people = "0"; ?>
<form name ="select_employee" id="select_employee" action="<?php echo    (base_url('index.php/employee_master/edit_employee/'.$id_people.''))?>" method="post">
<br />
<?php foreach($rows as $person) { ?>
<?php $id_people=$person['id_people']; ?>
<input type = "radio" class='rad_button' name = "employee_id" value="<?php echo $id_people ; ?>"/>

<?php
    foreach($person as $object){

        echo $object; ?>_______

    <?php } ?> <br> 

<?php } ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>


<script>
$(".rad_button").click(function() {
$("#select_employee").attr('action', "<?php echo     base_url('index.php/employee_master/edit_employee')?>" + "/" + $(this).attr('value'));
console.log($("#select_employee").attr('action'));
})
</script>
```

before, i was passing in the $id_people from post but i added the script that passes it in through url. here is the controller it is passed into.

```
public function edit_employee($id_people){

    if(empty($id_people)){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "please select an employee");
        redirect(base_url('index.php/employee_master'), 'refresh');
    } else {
            $this->load->model('employee_master_model');
            $info=$this->employee_master_model->get_info($id_people);//this will query the db every time form validation fails, may need to streamline

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->config('form_validation');

            if ($this->form_validation->run('employee_master/edit_employee') == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view("forms/edit_employee", $info);
            }

            else
            { . . . (unrelated part of the controller)...
```

when this controller loads forms/edit_employee the first time the validation_errors() is already populated with every error!? here is my config file that i am calling the validation rules from

```
<?php //contains validation rules for all forms in application. name of array corrisponds to controller name and function name

$config = array(
             'employee_master/add_employee' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'first_name',
                                        'label' => '"First Name"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'email',
                                        'label' => '"Email"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]|is_unique[people.email]|valid_email'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'last_name',
                                        'label' => '"Last Name"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'address',
                                        'label' => '"Address"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'city',
                                        'label' => '"City"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'state',
                                        'label' => '"State"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[2]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'marital_status',
                                        'label' => '"Marital Status"',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'ssn',
                                        'label' => '"Social Security"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[9]|numeric'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'acct_number',
                                        'label' => '"Account Number"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[15]|numberic'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'pay_rate',
                                        'label' => '"Pay Rate"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|numeric'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'direct_deposit',
                                        'label' => '"Direct Deposit"',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )

                                ),
             'employee_master/edit_employee' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'first_name',
                                        'label' => '"First Name"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'email',
                                        'label' => '"Email"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]valid_email'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'last_name',
                                        'label' => '"Last Name"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'address',
                                        'label' => '"Address"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'city',
                                        'label' => '"City"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[44]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'state',
                                        'label' => '"State"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[2]'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'marital_status',
                                        'label' => '"Marital Status"',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'ssn',
                                        'label' => '"Social Security"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[9]|numeric'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'acct_number',
                                        'label' => '"Account Number"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|max_length[15]|numberic'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'pay_rate',
                                        'label' => '"Pay Rate"',
                                        'rules' => 'required|numeric'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'direct_deposit',
                                        'label' => '"Direct Deposit"',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )


                                )                         
           );
```

Comment: What does your form validation config look like?

Comment: $config = array(
                 'employee_master/edit_employee' => array(array(...)) ... i just did it exactly like the manual says under the form validation heading "Associating a Controller Function with a Rule Group"

Comment: i have tried calling the form_validation->run() using a specific key for each controll group in the config file but i got the same result.

Comment: Edit your question to include the full array that you are using in the validation config. I also saw in a comment to one of the answers that you are leaving part of your controller out. Please post the entire `edit_employee()` method from the controller. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, wrap your form validation into:

```
if($this->input->post('submit_button_name_or_input_name'))
{
    // run validation
}
```

What's happening right now is your validation runs the second your form is displayed.

Comment: yeah i left that part out when i pasted the code for simplicity, sorry for the confusion. my application actually does have have an if statement to check  if the post value has been submitted. i am also autoloading the validation code from my config file corrisponding to the controller and function name which i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the validations in to variables

'$data ['form2_errors'] = validation_errors ();'

please refer this link